# data.table join and j-expression unexpected behavior

Tags: r, data.table

In `R 2.15.0` and `data.table 1.8.9`:

```
d = data.table(a = 1:5, value = 2:6, key = "a")

d[J(3), value]
#   a value
#   3     4

d[J(3)][, value]
#   4
```

I expected both to produce the same output (the 2nd one) and I believe they *should*.

In the interest of clearing up that this is not a `J` syntax issue, same expectation applies to the following (identical to the above) expressions:

```
t = data.table(a = 3, key = "a")
d[t, value]
d[t][, value]
```

I would expect both of the above to return the exact same output.

**So let me rephrase the question** - why is (`data.table` designed so that) the *key* column printed out automatically in `d[t, value]`?

**Update (based on answers and comments below):** Thanks @Arun et al., I understand the design-why now. The reason the above prints the *key* is because there is a hidden *by* present every time you do a `data.table` merge via the `X[Y]` syntax, and that `by` is by the key. The reason it's designed this way seems to be the following - since the `by` operation has to be performed when merging, one might as well take advantage of that and not do another `by` if you are going to do that by the key of the merge.

Now that said, I believe that's a syntax design flaw. The way I read `data.table` syntax `d[i, j, by = b]` is

> take `d`, apply the `i` operation (be that subsetting or merging or whatnot), and then do the `j` expression "by" b

The by-without-by breaks this reading and introduces cases one has to think about specifically (am I merging on `i`, is `by` just the key of the merge, etc). I believe this should be the job of the `data.table` - the commendable effort to make `data.table` faster in one particular case of the merge, when the `by` is equal to the key, should be done in an alternative way (e.g. by checking internally if the `by` expression is actually the key of the merge).

Comment: what it does now; also fwiw, `d[J(3), value := 10]` works as expected

Comment: huh? I don't think we understand each other. I think (in this case) `d[3, value]` and `d[J(3), value]` should produce the same result.

Comment: can we please change the title of this question.  The behavior is 100% expected and often leveraged.

Comment: @Arun imagine I write a function `fancy_sum(x, y)`, that would compute the sum of `x` and `y` normally, except when `x` is equal to 10, in which case it would multiply. Imagine this is also documented behavior, called *product-instead-of-sum*. While a documented *syntax design choice*, I would call that a clear *syntax design flaw*.

Comment: @Arun, again, please see https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2696&group_id=240&atid=978

Comment: @Arun, read the comment at the bottom of the FR. If that still doesn't get the point across, I don't know what would. You're talking about how things work, and why supplying different classes of inputs produces different results, while I'm talking about how things *should* work, and how different classes of inputs producing different results for this breaks user expectations.

Comment: This is apparently being changed soon.  See @Arun's comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20914724/636656

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [`data.table 1.9.3`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable), the default behavior has been changed and the examples below produce the same result. To get the *by-without-by* result, one now has to specify an explicit `by=.EACHI`:

```
d = data.table(a = 1:5, value = 2:6, key = "a")

d[J(3), value]
#[1] 4

d[J(3), value, by = .EACHI]
#   a value
#1: 3     4
```

And here's a slightly more complicated example, illustrating the difference:

```
d = data.table(a = 1:2, b = 1:6, key = 'a')
#   a b
#1: 1 1
#2: 1 3
#3: 1 5
#4: 2 2
#5: 2 4
#6: 2 6

# normal join
d[J(c(1,2)), sum(b)]
#[1] 21

# join with a by-without-by, or by-each-i
d[J(c(1,2)), sum(b), by = .EACHI]
#   a V1
#1: 1  9
#2: 2 12

# and a more complicated example:
d[J(c(1,2,1)), sum(b), by = .EACHI]
#   a V1
#1: 1  9
#2: 2 12
#3: 1  9
```

Comment: Since it's very likely that this post'll be *the* place to be looked at for this change, it'd make sense answer in detail. I'll also try to edit when I've some time.

Comment: @Arun I added a more complicated example, obviously feel free to edit

Comment: @Arun This change has been a major disrupt for me. I agree that from a new user perspective this might be more intuitive, but, wouldn't it be better if by = .EACHI is kept as the default for backwards compatibility? At least, it would be very important to give a big heads up to all the other packages that depend on data.table

Answer (score 11):

**Edit number Infinity:** Faq 1.12 *exactly* answers your question: (Also useful/relevant is [**FAQ 1.13**](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf), not pasted here).

> **1.12 What is the difference between X[Y] and merge(X,Y)?**
>   X[Y] is a join, looking up X's rows using Y (or Y's key if it has one) as an index. Y[X] is a join, looking up Y's rows using X (or X's key if it has one) as an index. merge(X,Y)1 does both ways at the same time. The number of rows of X[Y] and Y[X] usually dier; whereas the number of rows returned by merge(X,Y) and merge(Y,X) is the same. BUT that misses the main point. Most tasks require something to be done on the data after a join or merge. **Why merge all the columns of data, only to use a small subset of them afterwards?** 
>   You may suggest `merge(X[,ColsNeeded1],Y[,ColsNeeded2])`, but that takes copies of the subsets of data, and it requires the programmer to work out which columns are needed. **X[Y,j] in data.table does all that in one step for you**. When you write `X[Y,sum(foo*bar)]`, data.table
>   automatically inspects the j expression to see which columns it uses. It will only subset those columns only; the others are ignored. Memory is only created for the columns the j uses, and Y columns enjoy standard R recycling rules within the context of each group. Let's say foo is in X, and bar is in Y (along with 20 other columns in Y). **Isn't** `X[Y,sum(foo*bar)]` **quicker to program and quicker to run than a merge followed by a subset?**

---

Old answer which did *nothing* to answer the OP's question (from OP's comment), retained here because I believe it does).

When you give a value for `j` like `d[, 4]` or `d[, value]` in `data.table`, the `j` is evaluated as an `expression`. From the data.table FAQ 1.1 on accessing `DT[, 5]` (the very first FAQ) :

> Because, by default, unlike a data.frame, the 2nd argument is an expression which is evaluated within the scope of DT. 5 evaluates to 5.

The first thing, therefore, to understand is, in your case:

```
d[, value] # produces a "vector"
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

This is *not different* when the query for `i` is a basic indexing like:

```
d[3, value] # produces a vector of length 1
# [1] 4
```

However, this is *different* when `i` is by itself a `data.table`. From `data.table` introduction (page 6):

```
d[J(3)] # is equivalent to d[data.table(a = 3)]
```

Here, you are performing a `join`. If you just do `d[J(3)]` then you'd get all columns corresponding to that join. If you do,

```
d[J(3), value] # which is equivalent to d[J(3), list(value)]
```

Since you say this answer does *nothing* to answer your question, I'll point where the answer to your "rephrased" question, I believe, lies: ---> **then you'd get just that column, but since you're performing a join, the key column will also be output'd (as it's a join between two tables based on the key column).**

---

**Edit:** Following your 2nd edit, If your question is *why so*?, then I'd reluctantly (or rather ignorantly) answer, Matthew Dowle designed so to differentiate between a data.table `join-based-subset` and a `index-based-subset`ting operation.

Your second syntax is equivalent to:

```
d[J(3)][, value] # is equivalent to:

dd <- d[J(3)]
dd[, value]
```

where, again, in `dd[, value]`, `j` is evaluated as an expression and therefore you get a vector.

---

To answer your 3rd modified question: for the 3rd time, it's because it **is a JOIN between two data.tables** based on the key column. If I join two `data.table`s, I'd expect a `data.table`

From `data.table` introduction, once again:

> Passing a data.table into a data.table subset is analogous to A[B] syntax in base R where A is a matrix and B is a 2-column matrix. In fact, the A[B] syntax in base R inspired the data.table package.

Comment: Your comments helped me pinpoint where exactly my expectation breaks, so see OP edit. As is, this answer does nothing for my question.

Comment: Feel free to down-vote then. If anyone else who understands your question *and* my answer tells me that this answer *does nothing* to help your question, then I'd be happy to delete it.

Comment: @eddi I think this actually answers your question rather precisely.

Comment: my question is **why** is key printed out, not the explanation of **how** it's printed out!

Comment: as in the design-why, not the how-why, I really don't know how else to state it :)

Comment: @Arun, yes `A[B]` returns a `data.table`, so does `A`, does that mean that when you type `A[, value]` you expect a `data.table`? No. In any other usage of `i` except to join, you **don't** get a `data.table` when you write `A[i-expression, value]`. This is why `A[B, value]` breaks my expectation and I don't think you explained that design decision in your edits yet.

Comment: @eddi, when you do `merge` on two data.frames, do you expect the common columns to be returned?

Comment: yes, same as when I do `A[B]`. However `merge` doesn't have the `j` syntax for me to demonstrate `A[B, value]`, so I don't carry over any expectations from there.

Comment: `A[, value]` is *not* a `data.table` join. Why would I expect a `data.table`? `A[DT, value]` **is a join (merge) of two data.tables**, why wouldn't I expect a data.table? It's like asking, I merge two `data.frame`s and I don't get a vector...

Comment: Because for any other **i-expression**, `A[i, value]` is **not** a `data.table`.

Comment: So why do you expect a `data.table` when `i` is NOT a data.table as it is NOT a join/merge of two data.tables?

Comment: huh, wat? I don't expect a `data.table` from **any** `A[i, value]`, yet I get it when `i` is a `data.table`.

Comment: When `i` is a `data.table`, it's equivalent to joining two `data.tables`. Do you agree/understand?

Comment: If so, why wouldn't you expect the output to be a data.table? Why are you surprised that the join of two data.tables is a data.table?

Comment: :) this is an infinite loop, see 6 posts above

Comment: Here's how I read `d[i,j]` - take `d`, subset or join or do some other magic involving `i`, then do `j` for the result

Comment: X[Y] **is** a merge (also implemented by `merge.data.table` method). As such, I expect the intersecting column.

Comment: in `X[Y]`, I agree wholeheartedly, in `X[Y, value]`, emphatically no, for reasons two comments above

Comment: How about: `X[Y, list(value)]`?

Comment: Same logic, the output should be the same as `X[Y][, list(value)]` - take `X`, do `Y`, return `list(value)`

Comment: One last question: when you do `d[, list(.), by = .]`, why do you expect the columns in `by` to be in the result as well? Why not just the `list(.)` entries??

Comment: if you want expectations - because that's what `by` does, it doesn't break my `d[i,j]` expectation, because there is an extra `by`; as a design decision it's pretty obvious too, as most any usage of `by` requires having the `by` column at the end. This is not the case for `X[Y, j]` - at least I'm having a very hard time thinking of a usage case where I'd want to have the key there if I didn't request it explicitly in `j`.

Comment: Wow... I am now really interested in hearing what @MatthewDowle (sorry to drag you into this mess) has to say! It *clearly* answers your question! `Why merge all the columns of data, only to use a small subset of them afterwards?`

Comment: Finally getting somewhere (@Arun, I do appreciate the effort btw, even if we do/did speak past each other a lot) - from FAQ 1.13 - it seems like it's there because of the *by without by* or *grouping by i* feature, which at the moment doesn't make much sense to me, but explanations are welcome :)

Comment: @Arun, this is not about what to merge or how, but what to output at the end, you're again going somewhere else :)

Comment: and 1.14 cements the point of 1.13; I'm still confused about it, maybe tomorrow it will become more clear

Comment: Hmm, seems I've failed to understand every step of the way. I've tagged MatthewDowle. I'll leave it to the author of the package to take it from here. I'm of course interested to figure out what I (and arguably some of the `data.table` users here on SO) seem to have missed.

Comment: @Arun, while I think my question has been answered thanks to this discussion (and has been reduced to me wanting to submit a feature change request and not knowing how to do that or if that would even have any effect), I don't think your answer specifically answers it; so +1 and thanks for the effort and I consider the OP closed, but I don't think it makes sense to give your answer the checkmark

Comment: @eddi, shall we cleanup this comment section as well (before to delete the answer)?

Comment: @Arun I think this answer helped me out quite a bit in understanding the problem, and has a well-deserved +1 from me, so I'd vote against deleting it :)

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* unexpected behaviour, it is documented behaviour. Arun has done a good job of explaining and demonstrating in the FAQ where this is **clearly** documented.

there is a feature request [FR 1757](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=1757) that proposes the use of the `drop` argument in this case

When implemented, the behaviour you want might be coded

```
d = data.table(a = 1:5, value = 2:6, key = "a")

d[J(3), value, drop = TRUE]
```

Comment: thanks, I understand the design why now (which is, if you support by-without-by, then that's a hidden `by`, and so the `by` column should be there), and so far the conclusion of all this (for me) seems to be that by-without-by is a bad syntax feature to have (as opposed to manually specifying a `by` if you want to and default behavior of `X[Y,j]` being the same as `X[Y][,j]`). I'm very open to be convinced otherwise by some examples.

Comment: `by-without-by` is **significantly** faster than `by` or even a keyed `by`.  I think an extra couple of key strokes is worth it. If you want to  have a long drawn out discussion, move to the data.table mailing list. If you want to comment on the feature request for drop = TRUE, do so.

Comment: then that feature should come as an extra option, but not at a cost to normal syntax and understanding; anyway, my original question is answered I guess; fwiw another inconsistency in this by-without-by business is that the hidden `by` column is actually unavailable in the `j` expression, so that `d[J(3), a]` fails

Comment: by-without-by **is** normal data.table syntax . You could put in a feature request to remove by-without-by, but I think the problem is your understanding and expectations, which (clearly) are out of step with the data.table author (and the majority of users). `d[.(3), a]` is an interesting case, I'm not sure how that gets the result it does. If you name within `i` it (can) work `d[.(a=3), a]`. Perhaps this is worth a question by itself (on the mailing list perhaps)

Comment: @eddi -- I have created [FR 2693](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2693&group_id=240&atid=978) to automatically use the key column names when an unnamed list is passed to i

Comment: @mnel +1 for FR#2693. Will try and implement that.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Arun's answer. Here's another wording: After you do a join, you often will use the join column as a reference or as an input to further transformation. So you keep it, and you have an option to discard it with the (more roundabout) double `[` syntax. From a design perspective, it is easier to keep frequently relevant information and then discard when desired, than to discard early and risk losing data that is difficult to reconstruct.

Another reason that you'd want to keep the join column is that you can perform aggregate operations at the same time as you perform a join (the *by without by*). For example, the results here are much clearer by including the join column:

```
d <- data.table(a=rep.int(1:3,2),value=2:7,other=100:105,key="a")
d[J(1:3),mean(value)]
#   a  V1
#1: 1 3.5
#2: 2 4.5
#3: 3 5.5
```

Comment: I'm going to have think about this, but atm I don't quite understand the need for `d[J(1:3), mean(value)]` syntax for getting that result vs what I would consider much more palatable option of using `d[J(1:3), mean(value), by = a]` syntax (I actually haven't checked if this works, but I would *want* it to work this way). I guess I don't understand the need (and want) for the *by without by* syntax, as in my case all it does is just confuse with very little apparent benefit.

Comment: As @Simon101 quotes Prof. Ripley, "*Your preferences are irrelevant. It's the documentation that counts*" (and that *does not* fail to give explainations). That said, MatthewDowle is very nice and receptive and he may play along. I'm perfectly happy the way it is.

Comment: @eddi The motivation for _by-without-by_ is speed when you have a _subset_ of known groups. Say you have 1000 groups (each with 1000 rows and 100 columns), but you only want the mean of one column for only 6 groups. A subset of all columns for those 6 groups, followed by a `by` would be slower than a direct _by-without-by_ with fancy `j` column usage inspection. See FAQ 1.12 for more info on the thinking here.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I have nothing against the *concept* of by without by, my complaint is against its *syntax*. I believe the syntax should be "normal" by, and all of the magic should happen internally.

Comment: @eddi I see where you're coming from now, I think. In my case what I do a lot is `DT[myids,mean(stuff)]` or `DT[myids,list(mean(stuff),sd(stuff),...)]`. I like `data.table` giving me the aggregates for each `id` automatically, because that's what I need most of the time. I think I'd find having to set `by=` as well too onerous.

Comment: @eddi Also, _by-without-by_ only happens when `mult='all'`. I sometimes set `mult='first'`, or use `DT[myids][,mean(stuff)]` as the FAQ says. There is also a feature request in this area somewhere to be done.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, I created a feature request to change this behavior https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2696&group_id=240&atid=978 , I tried to explain there, as clearly as I could, why it broke my expectations and why I think current behavior is more complicated than it should be

Comment: @eddi, I'm a bit confused. How do you suggest to implement the concept of *by-**without**-by* using *normal by*? I guess you mean by `normal by` that, it should be of the form: `d[i, j, by=.]`. How will this be *by-**without**-by*? Could you elaborate? To me, the concept of `by-without-by` shouldn't involve `by` (as the name suggests). Since you have nothing against the concept, this confuses me.

Comment: @Arun, what I mean is that by-without-by is there because of performance improvements when you merge and then do a by by the key. That concept of doing both at the same time is a great one and will save time. But the syntax to achieve that behavior should not compromise the understanding of what `d[i,j,by=b]` means.

Comment: So basically you don't want the concept of `by-without-by`... Clearly your suggestion is *not* `by-without-by`.

Comment: I want the concept of speeding up when you by by the key, but not the current syntax. I don't want silent by's.

Comment: @Arun please see the feature request, I tried to be more clear there than I can be in this comment-space.

Comment: @eddi An `i` join with `mult='all'` is like `CROSS APPLY` in SQL, if that helps? If the same group appears in `i` twice then the same aggregate will be returned for both, in the same order as `i` (useful sometimes). Not sure how an `i` then `by` would work in this case (it may consider the two `i` dups as one?)

Comment: @eddi How about an option to turn off `by-without-by`?  In the usual way it would be a new argument to `[.data.table` with default taken from the global option. And that would simplify the answer to FAQ 1.14 nicely, too.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I don't really know SQL enough to draw an analogy. If you're going to go the option route, I think, ideally, turning *on* `by-without-by` syntax should be optional and not *off*. I get that this is version 1.8.9 and the change could be disruptive and that's one of your concerns. If introducing the option first, and then flipping it around a few versions later is the smoother way of doing it - that's cool, but I do believe that the end state should be that the default reading of `d[i,j,by=b]` is `take d, apply i, return j by b`, or `take d, apply i, return j` if there is no `by`.

Comment: @eddi Im happy to make it optional, since there's no downside really. Changing the default would need more people (on datatable-help) to agree with you. A full discussion there would be useful.

Comment: @MatthewDowle ok, I submitted a post to that mailing-list