# Including all permutations when using data.table[,,by=...]

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` that I am collapsing to the month level using `,by`.

There are 5 by vars, with # of levels: `c(4,3,106,3,1380)`.  The 106 is months, the 1380 is a geographic unit.  As in turns out there are some 0's, in that some cells have no values.  `by` drops these, but I'd like it to keep them.

Reproducible example:

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
s <- function(n,l=5) sample(letters[seq(l)],n,replace=TRUE)
dat <- data.table( x=runif(n), g1=s(n), g2=s(n), g3=s(n,25) )
datCollapsed <- dat[ , list(nv=.N), by=list(g1,g2,g3) ]
datCollapsed[ , prod(dim(table(g1,g2,g3))) ] # how many there should be: 5*5*25=625
nrow(datCollapsed) # how many there are
```

Is there an efficient way to fill in these missing values with 0's, so that all permutations of the by vars are in the resultant collapsed data.table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd also go with a cross-join, but would use it in the `i`-slot of the original call to `[.data.table`:

```
keycols <- c("g1", "g2", "g3")                       ## Grouping columns
setkeyv(dat, keycols)                                ## Set dat's key
ii <- do.call(CJ, sapply(dat[, ..keycols], unique))  ## CJ() to form index
datCollapsed <- dat[ii, list(nv=.N)]                 ## Aggregate

## Check that it worked
nrow(datCollapsed)
# [1] 625
table(datCollapsed$nv)
#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
# 135 191 162  82  39  13   3
```

This approach is referred to as a "by-without-by" and, as documented in `?data.table`, it is just as efficient and fast as passing the grouping instructions in via the `by` argument:

> Advanced: Aggregation for a subset of known groups is
>   particularly efficient when passing those groups in `i`. When
>   `i` is a `data.table`, `DT[i,j]` evaluates `j` for each row
>   of `i`. We call this *by without `by`* or *grouping by `i`*. 
>   Hence, the self join `DT[data.table(unique(colA)),j]` is
>   identical to `DT[,j,by=colA]`.

Comment: Just a note: there's a [FR here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2696&group_id=240&atid=978) and we plan to move `by-without-by` to `by`. That is, `X[Y]` should do **just a join** and if one wants to replicate the old behaviour, then one needs to do: `X[, j, by=Y, mult=, nomatch=]` (or something like that). This is to retain consistency with `by` doing the job of `by` always and not polluted by `i` doing `by` in just 1 case.

Comment: Thanks!  This works beautifully.  Returns a slightly different answer (after ignoring all the NAs it adds in for the missing permutations), in that any `keycol` values that are `NA` it will include but the value of `nv` will be `NA`.  I can guess why this happens, but might be good to return a warning in that case.  Solution is just to recode the `NA`s in `keycol` vars beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Make a cartesian join of the unique values, and use that to join back to your results

```
dat.keys <- dat[,CJ(g1=unique(g1), g2=unique(g2), g3=unique(g3))]
setkey(datCollapsed, g1, g2, g3)
nrow(datCollapsed[dat.keys])  # effectively a left join of datCollapsed onto dat.keys
# [1] 625
```

Note that the missing values are NA right now, but you can easily change that to 0s if you want.