# Using := in data.table with subset for i and a vector for update

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to update specific entries of a data.table.  My i subset is another data.table.  When I try to pass the := command a vector that is the same length as the subset, I get a warning.  I can solve this with a loop, but I assume that there's a better way.  This code replicates my results:

```
DT <- data.table(ID = 1:10,V = rnorm(10))
setkey(DT,ID)
DT.alt <- DT[ID < 5,] ##Create a data.table with a subset of the observations
setkey(DT.alt,ID)
DT[,V:=rnorm(10)] ## Works
DT[DT.alt,V:=rnorm(1)]  ## Works
DT[DT.alt,V:=rnorm(4)] ## Warning and the first element is used for all rows
```

Note that this works, but do I really need a loop?

```
for(i in 1:dim(DT.alt)[1]) DT[DT.alt[i,],V:=rnorm(1)]
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I get no error using `data.table` version 1.9.3 from r-forge. Which package version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 1.9.2, should have stated that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `data.table` versions <= 1.9.2, a `join` of the form `x[i, j=...]` - that is, a join where `j` is also used was designed to be an *implicit by* (or) `by-without-by` operation. In other words, this'll calculate `j` for each value in `i`. So it won't work as you intend.

This design choice has been changed in the [current development version 1.9.3](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240) (which'll at some point be pushed to CRAN versioned 1.9.4), for consistency, after feedback from a lot of users. You can check the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093289/data-table-join-and-j-expression-unexpected-behavior/), [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/changing-data-table-by-without-by-syntax-to-require-a-quot-by-quot-td4664770.html) and the feature request (FR) [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2696&group_id=240&atid=978).

So in `1.9.3`, this will work as intended (as @BenBarnes points out). That is, by default, `x[i, j=...]` will first perform the `join` and the evaluate `j` after, once, instead of obtaining `j` for each `i`. If instead you'd like the old behaviour, you'll have to explicitly state `by` as follows:

```
## v 1.9.3
## performs the join and then calculates/evaluates j
x[i, j]
## explicitly state by to obtain j for each i
x[i, j, by=.EACHI]
```

When this version hits CRAN, there should also be a provision to use the old version (so that existing code doesn't break), with a warning that this feature will be deprecated in the next release (or something like that - how this'll be done is not finalised yet).

To summarise, your code will work as intended from versions `>= 1.9.3`.

> Note that `.EACHI` feature is not yet documented in `?data.table`. This is still a development version. When it's being released to CRAN, you can find the documentation for `.EACHI` in `?data.table`, where all the other special variables like `.I`, `.N`, `.GRP`, `.BY` etc.. are also documented.

HTH

---

Edit: If you've to do this efficiently using `<= 1.9.2`, then you can do it by first finding the matching indices as follows:

```
idx = DT[DT.alt, which=TRUE]
DT[idx, V := rnorm(length(idx))]
```

Comment: +1 for clarity and details. Just wondering if there is a place I can learn about "all" these functionalities like: .EACHI, .I etc.